# Any way to build test project to standalone exe?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, nunit

I have NUnit test project in my solution. I'd like to be able to run its tests on a set of different environments using a network of virtual machines and then aggregate result XMLs from each machine to my server.

I guess I would need to install NUnit to all my VMs in order to do it that way. But maybe I can avoid it somehow? Hypotetically I can change my test assembly's output type from class library to console app and call all my test methods (those ones with right NUnit attributes) using reflection manually from Main method and write XML output myself.

So I'd like to know if there are any testing framework that can make it for me. Ideally I would like it to create standalone executable that I will be able to run on a bare installed system, with no need to install some additional testing software. This executable will run all its tests and generate some test result output (it better be NUnit-compatible, but it's fine if it's not, I can handle some post processing).

Any ideas how I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the whole idea of testing framework is - you install it and it tests your code by finding specially marked classes and methods, and then reports on it, while you can manipulate behavior. But yea, you definitely can write your tests without any framework. Who stops you from writing exe application that makes calls your DLLs, and executes its methods and checks values or output?

Comment: Would using a CI build framework, such as TeamCity or CruiseControl, be an option? You could set up the VMs as build servers and the framework would take care of a lot of the heavy lifting.

Comment: @T.S. kinda did it already. Wheel inventing can go a long way, maybe there are some tools for it I'm not aware off.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge not sure I got you right. There can be a lot of VMs, I want to install as less additional software on them as possible. But thanks for advice anyways.

Comment: Well, I like your question but if your question is mainly to help you find a tool than your question belongs to this according to SO: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic**

Comment: CI with a test agents with your preinstalled environments... Or am I getting your question wrong?

Comment: @SimpleV , were you able to find a solution for your task?

Comment: @AntonK it was almost 8 years ago and I barely remember anything. Infrastructure as a code was a very fresh and new thing, and we used Windows machines on Azure. I ended up making an "OS image" that has NUnit preinstalled on it. CI was spinning up a new VM, waiting for it to provision, then I think I had to somehow start a UI session on it with some sort of command (`mstsc`?) because I had UI tests. Then I could run my `.bat` file with `PsExec` that was downloading pre-built `.dll`s with tests from CI artifacts, running NUnit on them, and uploading test run result XMLs back to CI.